# How can I access COM automation DLLs from Java?

Tags: java, dll, automation, com, jna

I have a third party application which includes a suite of DLL libraries that provide access to the application's data and commands.

Using Java, I want to access these DLLs in order to retrieve some specific data and write it to a file.

While similar questions to this have been asked before, I haven't found any that have helped me (I'm an absolute beginner at Java). I suspect this can be done with 
JNA but need some guidance. It might be beyond my novice ability but I want to try.

There are several DLL files I need to access, each of which contain multiple libraries, which provide access to objects offering various functionality.

I need to gain access to these DLLs, instantiate objects from them, and gain access to the methods and variables provided. Is there a relatively easy Java solution that anyone knows of?

Thanks

EDIT: I've added example J++ code illustrating what I need to do in Java. J++ would firstly require creating COM wrappers for each of the required DLL files.

```js
import dll1.*;
import dll2.*;
import dll3.*;
import com.ms.com.*;

public class Class1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create an application object
        dll3.Application app = new dll3.Application();

        // Use the getDataManager() method on the  application
        // object to get the DataManager object (which in turn is
        // used to create the price object)  
        DataManager dm;

        try {
            dm = app.getDataManager();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return;
        }

        // Create the price data object using the CreateOb method of the
        // DataManager object
        PriceOb dp = (PriceOb) dm.CreateOb("Price");

        // Set the requests parameters and make the request
        dp.setVar1("abc");
        dp.setVar2("xyz");
        dp.Request();
```

Comment: [JACOB](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/) is a JAVA-COM Bridge that allows you to call COM Automation components from Java.

Comment: JNA can easily let you link to the DLLs as long as you have the API for the methods.  The JNA github site has many examples.  You need to include a specific example in your question for more specific help.

Comment: Thanks for both your suggestions. Having a read about both those two frameworks I'm not even sure it is possible to achieve what I need. I need to instantiate an object of a particular type from one DLL, then from this object instantiate another object of a type defined in a different DLL, but I'm not sure if it is possible to export classes. I'll include some example J++ code that illustrates the requirement.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: with J++ do you mean visual j++? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_J%2B%2B

Comment: Yes, I believe it is Visual J++.